# /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lrdmacm

Tags: compiling

I am building tensorflow from source. When I was compiling it with bazel, I got the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/hasan/build/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:2995:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' failed (Exit 1)
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lrdmacm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.020s, Critical Path: 4.47s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

How I can solve the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Is `librdmacm-dev` installed?